# Difference between condition check with hard code value on join and where?

Tags: sql-server

Should we check condition with hard coded value on join?

```
     select * from user u
     inner join department d on d.id = u.id and d.id =1 
     where u.id = 1
```

If yes? what is the different between "inner join department d on d.id = u.id and d.id =1 " and "where u.id = 1".
What is happening internally in sql server?

Comment: There should be no difference.  Look at the execution plans of the two queries to see for yourself.

Comment: Unclear: does u.id contain the department ??

Comment: In this case conditions in the join shouldn't make a difference to the query. Where conditions in the join can be useful however is with outer joins

Answer (score 1):

The FROM clause (including JOINS) is processed before the WHERE.   When you add the hard-code variable in the JOIN, you creating a smaller result set for the WHERE clause to process, potentially improving performance.

Run your query using count(*) and set how many rows coming back with the d.id=1 on the JOIN.   This is the number of rows the WHERE clause will need to consider.

Now add the condition and get the count again.   This is (hopefully0 a smaller number of rows to consider.

However, keep in mind the SQL Query optimizer is pretty smart and may do some optimizations on a simple query as your example above.

Comment: Actually, the query processing engine is usually smart enough to see the WHERE and the JOIN, and filter the joined table before doing the join.  Again, if you have any doubts, see the execution plan.

Comment: @Sparky: this ("the FROM clause is processed before the WHERE clause...") does not seem to be true: see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/70efeffe-76b9-4b7e-b4a1-ba53f5d21916/order-of-execution-of-sql-queries (particularly the comment accepted as the answer). As Tab Alleman says, SQL Server is free to adjust the order as it sees fit.

Comment: I agree Dave, the optimizer can do whatever it wants and is darn smart.  While the FROM clause with JOIN is generally processed first, the optimizer will decide the best approach